# Two network interfaces, can't access to public one from internal network

Tags: routing, ip, ethernet

I have a server with two network cards:

- eth0 -> public static ip
- eth1 -> local network dhcp

Both cards are connected to the same modem.

If I enable only eth0, I can access from local network (and from internet) using its subdomain or public ip.

If I connect also eth1, I can access from local network only using internal ip, and from internet (obviusly) using only public ip / subdomain.

How can I access this machine from public ip also from other machines on local network with eth1 enabled?

Edit: I have no gateway on second interface, and ip_forward is already enabled.

Here the config:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address x.x.x.x
netmask 255.255.255.248
nameserver 8.8.8.8
gateway x.x.x.y


auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Routing doesn't working in linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/336510/routing-doesnt-working-in-linux)

Comment: I added some extra infos. It doesn't seem the same problem.

Comment: It's not clear what your goal is.  Do you want local and Internet users to reach via public IP?

Comment: If i ping public ip set on eth0, it doesn't work (from local network, it works from outside). If I disable eth1 I can ping it. Of course I want to reach public ip from local network too.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a diagram of your network?  There may be other ways of solving this problem.